# How to use fprintf for writing data to a file

Tags: c

I want to write data from a C program to a file, so that Excel can read the file to plot a graph of the data. But I'm not sure of the exact syntax to use for fprintf.
I have stdlib.h declared in the very top of my program. I declared "File *fp;" in main but I'm      getting that File and fp are undeclared. What could be the problem?

**EDIT: My program compiles and runs but now my output file doesn't contain any data
This is what I have at the end of a while loop that does some computations..

```
 fp = fopen( "out_file.txt", "w" ); // Open file for writing

 fprintf(fp, "x = %f, y = %f, vx = %f, vy = %f, time = %f, ", x,y,vx,vy,time);
```

Comment: It's `FILE` not `File`. If that's not it you need to post more info.

Comment: Which C book are you learning from?

Comment: @kachilous Not going to become a C programmer, then.

Comment: code snippets from web sites are not going to get you too far - a book provides far better information (and more depth besides)

Comment: and, just out of curiosity, any error checking that the file was actually opened?  (See what you might have learned from a book)

Comment: my program works correctly. and yes a book probably would have been more helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your logic should look something like this:

```
fp = fopen( "out_file.txt", "w" ); // Open file for writing

while ( some condition )
{

    ... some calculations

    fprintf(fp, "x = %f, y = %f, vx = %f, vy = %f, time = %f, ", x,y,vx,vy,time);
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: thanks!! now this is sort of unrelated, but would I be able to simply import this in to Excel so that I could get a graph of the data?

Comment: You'd have to change your file format a little bit for Excel to easily read it. Either CSV or tab delimited may be the easiest, e.g. `fprintf(fp, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", x,y,vx,vy,time);`

Comment: Your welcome. If this is what you needed, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

The stdio file type is `FILE` (all uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

should be enough, but be careful because the structure's name is FILE (all uppercase) and not File. Finally, dont forget to close the file calling fclose()

Comment: thanks but now the statement:                                             fprintf("x = %f, y = %f, vx = %f, vy = %f, time = %f, ", x,y,vx,vy,time); is giving me an error "incompatible pointer type and incompatible argument"

Comment: @kachilous: because prinff wants as first argument a pointer to the FILE structure: fprintf(file, "%d", 45)

Comment: @BlackBear - it compiles and runs now but my output file does not contain any data. I have a while loop that does some computations and then at the end                                                  fp = fopen( "out_file.txt", "w" ); // Open file for writing
    
fprintf(fp, "x = %f, y = %f, vx = %f, vy = %f, time = %f, ", x,y,vx,vy,time);

Comment: @kachilous - keep updating your question - it's too hard to read the inline source.  also, do a printf exactly like your fprintf (minus the fp) so that you can tell if your loop is being reach.  (BTW, You probably need to fclose or fflush your fp)

Comment: @kachilous have you closed the file? @KevinDTimm: ops, right :)